# Trouble loading tensorflow keras model in databricks from Azure data lake using python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, databricks, azure-data-lake

I have a model that I saved inside a project_name in a container in azure data lake. I am having issues when loading a tensorflow model from databricks. Everything is already working fine as I tested out in jupyter notebook previously. I have to migrate the code in databricks.

This is a code I ran.

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("abfss://dev@abcproddatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/hkay/project_name/model/keras2.tf", compile=False)
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3129204037083358> in <module>
      3 
      4 ## Loading a model
----> 5 model = tf.keras.models.load_model("abfss://dev@abcproddatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/hkay/project_name/model/keras2.tf", compile=False)

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-03228642-df50-44d1-8e0e-f760ea5a0429/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-03228642-df50-44d1-8e0e-f760ea5a0429/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py in file_exists_v2(path)
    288   """
    289   try:
--> 290     _pywrap_file_io.FileExists(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
    291   except errors.NotFoundError:
    292     return False

UnimplementedError: File system scheme 'abfss' not implemented (file: 'abfss://dev@abcproddatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/hkay/project_name/model/keras2.tf')
```

It was running fine when I ran it in jupyter notebook. The model was saved locally when I was using jupyter.

The connection is working because I tested out the connection through reading the files from the path. The size of this model is 1.6 GB. I am not sure why it is not working. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Unfortunately, Keras doesn't understand URIs. it is designed to
> work only with local files ,so you need to use local path saving or
> loading data .***

Try to use `dbutils.fs.cp` it will copy data from Storage URL
`abfss://dev@axxx` to local path.

Copy file into `/tmp/model.tf` and load it.

```
#Setup storage configuration
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net","<access_key>")

dbutils.fs.cp("abfss://dev@abcproddatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/hkay/project_name/model/keras2.tf","/tmp/Demo_model.tf")
```

you can check weather model copied or not using below code.

```
display(dbutils.fs.ls("/tmp/Demo_model.tf"))
```

**Loading model:**

```
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model("/tmp/Demo_model.tf")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it and it gives this error. I already checked out the file using dbutils.fs.ls in the directory and I see the model is there. 
OSError: No file or directory found at /tmp/model/keras2.tf

Comment: hi @hkay, try to use `dbutils.fs.cp("abfss://dev@abcproddatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/hkay/project_name/model/keras2.tf","/dbfs/mnt/path")` . using this command, it copies model data to separate `/dbfs` path. Then use loading model.